# Multiple Disjunctive Conditions for MS Access Subforms

Tags: ms-access, subform

In configuring a MS Access subform, you can link master fields in the parent form to child fields in the child form. You can also have multiple links, but multiple links are conjunctive, e.g. having 2 links results in only rows that satisfy both link 1 *and* link 2.

I'm trying to have multiple disjunctive links (link 1 *or* link 2).

To provide more context, I have a table that expresses relationships between two objects so it includes two foreign keys referring to the same table. In the subform, I want to include rows in which the object's ID matches either foreign keys.

Comment: I doubt that is possible. Why would you want a UNION query as form RecordSource? Query is not editable.

Comment: @June7 I provided my reason in my question. Also, I'm sure I'm not the only person who has subforms that have a more complex relationship with the parent form than Access' linking system can accommodate.

Comment: Union query was your attempt to resolve issue but you don't really want a union, certainly not if you want an editable dataset. Answers are offering valid solution for form. Have you thought about how to present data in a report? That's where a UNION might be useful.

Comment: @June7 When I used the word 'union', I was referring to behavior and not the actual SQL operator. I've edited the title for clarity. Sorry for the misunderstanding. But yes, I do want the subform to be editable, which is why the solution I posted below is ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have mentioned, it is not possible to use MS Access' very basic linking system to do anything more than inner joins. However, I managed to figure out a simple workaround: using the parent form's `Current` event to update the subform's `RecordSource`.

This solution is a general one that can be used for subforms that have a more complex relationship with the parent form:

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
    Dim sql as String

    'This is the SQL statement for my situation, but you can write anything.
    sql = "SELECT * FROM SourceTable WHERE fk1 = " & Me![ID] & " OR fk2 = " & Me![ID]
    SubformName.Form.RecordSource = sql
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible.

Regard the Master/Child link fields as a *filter* or an *inner join*.